# Is $\sum_{i = 1}^{n} ({X_i}^2 - {\bar{X}}^2) \ge 0$?

Tags: probability

All $X_i \ge 0$ and $\bar{X} = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i = 1}^{n} X_i$.

Can we get this inequality $\sum_{i = 1}^{n} ({X_i}^2 - {\bar{X}}^2) \ge 0$?

**EDIT**:
Thanks to *Landon Carter*, I found $\sum_{i=1}^n(X_i-\bar X)^2 = \sum_{i=1}^n(X_i^2 -\bar X^2)$, the proof is as follows:

\begin{align*}
\sum_{i=1}^n(X_i-\bar X)^2
&=\sum_{i=1}^n(X_i^2-2X_i\bar X+\bar X^2)\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^nX_i^2-2\sum_{i=1}^nX_i\bar X+\sum_{i=1}^n\bar X^2\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^nX_i^2-n\bar X^2\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^n(X_i^2 -\bar X^2)\\
&\ge 0.
\end{align*}

Comment: It may or may not be true. You may experiment wioth some examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Expand $0\leq \sum_{i=1}^n (X_i - \overline{X})^2$